# Editing files outside of the public_html folder from inside the public_html folder

Tags: php

Using php, how can I edit a file that is located in a folder outside of the public_html folder from a file that is located inside the public_html folder?  I tried using the include function for the filename of the file outside of the public_html folder, but it runs the external file displaying contents of it (using fputs) for the current file instead of just updating the external file.

```
<?php 
include "hits.txt"; 
$filename = "hits.txt"; 
$count = file($filename); 
$count[0]++; 
$file = fopen ($filename, "w") or die ("Cannot find $filename"); 
fputs($file, "$count[0]"); 
fclose($file); 
?>
```

Comment: <?php
include "hits.txt";
$filename = "hits.txt";
$count = file($filename);
$count[0]++;
$file = fopen ($filename, "w") or die ("Cannot find $filename");
fputs($file, "$count[0]");
fclose($file);
?>

Comment: I added your code to your original question. FYI, next timeyou can edit your question instead of comment. People like to see the code formatted. Welcome to SO. :)

Comment: Thank you.  Next time I will include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to simply edit a file in the parent directory? To do this, you'll need to provide the open function with either an absolute/relative path to your file. That is:

```
$file_relative = "../../file.txt";
$file_absolute = "/some_file/www/file.txt";

fopen($file_relative, "w");

// Edit your file as necessary
```

Please note, that while this is technically feasible, it may be disallowed. You may not have the appropriate permissions to edit anything above public_html.